# Run on Sentence Question

Tags: run-on-sentence

Do I need a comma between again and so? It looks like it's a run on sentence.

> Are you going to be able to give us access to Las Vegas again so we
>   can at least jump back and forth between the servers to find files?

Comment: It is not a run-on sentence; the _so_ constituent is a dependent subordinate clause functioning as a purpose adjunct (adverbial); not an independent one and hence not able to cause a 'run-on' construction.

Comment: I'd add a comma here, though only for ease of reading: Are you going to be able to give us access to Las Vegas again, so that we can at least jump back and forth between the servers to find files?

Answer (score -2):

Edit: Original answer was wrong; all credit to [BillJ](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/141248/billj) for the correct answer (in comments)

> Although the so clause is finite and hence appears to be an independent main clause, it is in fact subordinate (dependent). It gives the purpose of us giving access to Las Vegas again (hence 'purpose adjunct'). It is marked as subordinate by the subordinator "so"; thus the clause must be subordinate, not independent. Adjuncts are optional elements that are not required grammatically.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with that. The _so_ clause is not an independent one; it is a subordinate (dependent) clause functioning as a purpose adjunct.

Comment: What does that mean? Can someone help explains it in more details?

Comment: @BillJ How so? I don't understand what you mean by "purpose adjunct"

Comment: @Tony Although the _so_ clause is finite and hence appears to be an independent main clause, it is in fact subordinate (dependent). It gives the purpose of us giving access to Las Vegas again (hence 'purpose adjunct'). It is marked as subordinate by the subordinator "so"; thus the clause must be subordinate, not independent. Adjuncts are optional elements that are not required grammatically.

Comment: @user142781 Please see my message to Tony, above.

Comment: @BillJ I see what you mean. You're right; I was thinking the "so" was a coordinating conjunction.